# how subscribe to buddylist using resource list xml

Tags: xml, sip, subscribe, jain-sip, opensips

I need to implement a SIP subscription to a resource list, under which tag I should put the XML buddy list that contains the desired SIP ID (to monitor their states). Note that I'm using Jain-SIP API, and I implemented the single subscription and is working fine, but I'm facing difficulties in working with multiple resource to monitor.
The XML that should be added as indicated in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5367

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource-lists xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:resource-lists"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<list>
<entry uri="sip:bill@example.com" />
<entry uri="sip:joe@example.org" />
<entry uri="sip:ted@example.net" />
</list>
</resource-lists>
```

I wish to build the SIP request with the buddy list XML:

```
SUBSCRIBE  sip:rls@example.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP terminal.example.com;branch=z9hG4bKwYb6QREiCL
Max-Forwards: 70
To: RLS <sip:rls@example.com>
From: <sip:adam@example.com>;tag=ie4hbb8t
Call-ID: cdB34qLToC@terminal.example.com
CSeq: 1 SUBSCRIBE
Contact: <sip:terminal.example.com>
Event: presence
Expires: 7200
Require: recipient-list-subscribe
Supported: eventlist
Accept: application/cpim-pidf+xml
Accept: application/rlmi+xml
Content-Type: application/resource-lists+xml
Content-Disposition: recipient-list
Content-Length: 337

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resource-lists xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:resource-lists"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<list>
<entry uri="sip:bill@example.com" />
<entry uri="sip:joe@example.org" />
<entry uri="sip:ted@example.net" />
</list>
</resource-lists>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tag"? I mean, you're XML body seems perfectly fine for me.

Comment: HI @jcm, I meant by TAG which Header. I'm using Jain-Sip Java API to build the SIP request. I create Headers (TO , from, via, content-Type,contact,etc) then add them to the request. My question was is which header should I put the XML?, because I don't have Body header.

Comment: HI @jcm, as for my original question, do you have an idea how to recognize whether my SIP Server can handle the SUBSCRIPTION to a resource list. example what I should put in TO header to adress to the RLS (resource List server). pbx model: User-Agent: FortiVoice/7.31b00. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using `javax.sip.message.Message` interface or an instance to a [`javax.sip.message.SIPRequest`](https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/jain-sip/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/javadoc/gov/nist/javax/sip/message/SIPRequest.html) object to create outgoing SUBSCRIBE request. In this case, you can use [`setContent`](https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/jain-sip/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/javadoc/gov/nist/javax/sip/message/SIPMessage.html#setContent%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.sip.header.ContentTypeHeader%29) method to specify request's body content.

On the other hand, the way to properly detect if your server supports multiple recipient subscription is by sending a OPTIONS request and, in corresponding 200 OK response, checking that *Supported:* header contains `recipient-list-subscribe` option tag. SIP message flow should be something like:

```
Client UA                        Server
 |                              |
 |----------------------------->|
 |            OPTIONS           |
 |<-----------------------------|
 |             200 OK           |
 |      (Contains Supported:    |
 |    recipient-list-subscribe  |
 |                              |
 |----------------------------->|
 |           SUBSCRIBE          |
 |<-----------------------------|
 |             200 OK           |
```

Comment: Hi @jcm, thank you it works, I used the setcontent and xml is added successfully to the SIP request: request.setContent(sipClientBO.getResourceXMLasString(), contentTypeHd);

Comment: HI @jcm, as for my original question, do you have an idea how to recognize whether my SIP Server can handle the SUBSCRIPTION to a resource list. example what I should put in TO header to adress to the RLS (resource List server). pbx model: User-Agent: FortiVoice/7.31b00. thank you

Comment: @Gladiator Please, check my last update for knowing if server supports subscriptions to request container resource list.

Comment: Hi @jcm, you said to send Options request in 200 Ok response, did you meant by this to keep the same callerId and other parameters(via:branch) in the dialog?and re-send them?. The case I created an Options request (with new callerId, branch), the server has responded without the "SUpported" header. I updated you answer with SIP messages, hope they will post it here.

Comment: @Gladiator No no, I said to send a SIP OPTIONS request and, **on its 200 OK response**, check _Supported_ header. SIP OPTIONS is an independent transaction used to know other end's capabilities. Check my update to the answer.

Comment: Hi @jcm, Ok I got your point, I sent Options request, and the server respond with 200 Ok but it doesn't contain Support header, seems the server won't reveal its features!. Below the response:
Received response: SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP localIp:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1833057213
From: <sip:MySipID@proxyserverIp:5060>;tag=1911372146
To: <sip:MySipID@proxyserverIp:5060>
Call-ID: dd078462328d570193aee5d50938c3d6@192.168.5.110
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
User-Agent: FortiVoice/7.31b00
Content-Length: 0

Comment: @Gladiator It seems your server is using SIP OPTIONS as a ping mechanism and, as you stated, hiding some network information, this means, you would need to work blindly, this is, send SUBSCRIBE request with corresponding body and Content-type and, if it's not supported, server should answer you with an error response (intialy, 400 Bad Request) instead of 200 OK

Comment: Hi @jcm I have sent a Subscription that contains a target SIPID1 in TO header field, and also the resource-list xml described above. The server has responded with a NOTIFY that includes the state of SIPID1, and seems he didn't send the state of the extensions mentioned in the xml resource list. Seems the server manipulate this request as a subscriptions to One Extension instead to a list. Note that I have included all the header in the above subscription request (required, supported..). However I will loop thru the SIP_IDs and should got their states sequentially instead of using the res-lst

Comment: @Gladiator Well, initially, seems the only possibility. On the other hand, you can check if [RFC 4662](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4662) is supported by your server. This will require that you create a URI that contains all desired entities. A part of this, it seems that I couldn't help much :-(. Hope my answer helps some else.

Comment: Hi @jcm, you'r always welcome, you helped me a lot,The sip server/ IP-PBX I worked on don't support list subscription or group creation. I will proceed with the peer-to-peer mechanism.